# how to include the file in asp.net for javascript, css and menus?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am new to .NET. How i can use include files for my menus? I am used to do with php is I make one php file with menu and I include it in all PHP files so that it can be changed in all pages when I would change it basic file. I dont know what is the concept of it in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.NET, there is the concept of **[Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)** that can be used to include commonly required files. Master pages can be nested, meaning that a Master Page can be derived from another master page, thereby allowing you to compose a page from multiple *"pages/files"*. Inside of a Page template, you specify the Master Page file to use, inside of the **[Page Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx)**.

If you're just starting out in .NET web applications, may I suggest taking a look at **[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)** and the Razor View Engine, a more terse and cleaner syntax for generating HTML. Razor has a similar concept to Master Pages, but they are known as Layouts and these can also be nested.

Comment: how to use config file which we usually use for predefined variables etc username and password?

Comment: There are many ways to do this, one of which could be inheritance - in ASP.NET web forms, create a base Page class from which you derive your pages; in ASP.NET MVC, create a base controller from which you derive your controllers.